# How to upload image without refreshing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an image uploader that can can upload an image and display it in another div. So far I have been able to display the image but let's say I change my mind and backspace the image(which deletes the image) and then again when i try to upload the second time around(without refreshing the page), the image doesn't appear at all. I even doubt if the change function runs the second time around(console.log doesn't fire). Can you tell How I can upload image without refreshing? I have set the `multiple ="true"` on input tag as well.

edit: (added snippet on request). As per the mina's answer, changed my code to `input.value = ''`. It was not there in the original posting.

```js
document.querySelector('.imageUploader').addEventListener("click", function(e){
 document.querySelector('.imageInput').value= ''; document.querySelector('.imageInput').click();
   document.querySelector('.imageInput').addEventListener('change', ev => {

   let theFile = ev.target.files
   for (var i = 0; i < theFile.length; i++) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(theFile[i]);
     reader.onload = function(){
       let dataURL = reader.result;
       let el = document.createElement("img")
       el.setAttribute('src', dataURL )
       let node =  document.querySelector('.textDiv')
       node.appendChild(el);
     }
    }
  })
 })
```

```html
<div class="imageUploader" style="width:50px; height: 50px; background-color: gray"></div>
<input type="file" class="imageInput" name="file" style="display:none;" multiple="true"/>
<div class="textDiv" contenteditable="true" style = "border: 1px solid black; height: 200px;"> </div>
```

Comment: It probably wont solve your problem, but shouldnt the addEventListener('change' ...) be outside of the click event handler? that way, on every click, you're adding another change listener if i am not mistaken

Comment: Placing change outside will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about `change` event, it will not re-execute except if you choose another image/file.

So to make it able to choose the same `image` again you need to reset the `input file` value.

```
input.value = ''
```

```js
 document.querySelector('.imageInput').addEventListener('change', ev => {

   let theFile = ev.target.files
   for (var i = 0; i < theFile.length; i++) {
     let reader = new FileReader();
     reader.readAsDataURL(theFile[i]);
     reader.onload = function(){
       let dataURL = reader.result;
       let el = document.createElement("img")
       el.setAttribute('src', dataURL )
       let node =  document.querySelector('.textDiv')
       node.appendChild(el);
     }
    }
  })

document.querySelector('.imageUploader').addEventListener("click", function(e){
 document.querySelector('.imageInput').value= ''; 
 document.querySelector('.imageInput').click();
})
```

```html
<div class="imageUploader" style="width:50px; height: 50px; background-color: gray"></div>
<input type="file" class="imageInput" name="file" style="display:none;" multiple="true"/>
<div class="textDiv" contenteditable="true" style = "border: 1px solid black; height: 200px;"> </div>
```

Comment: This is working. I'm able to upload images again and again. However, the image i have deleted also appears along with the newly uploaded image.

Comment: So, I think may there is an issue with the delete image method.

Comment: So this is what is happening - when i upload image one i.e. img1.jpg, and then delete it. Then upload another image which is image2.jpg. it actually makes a copy of image2.jpg twice. So image2.jpg is rendered twice but img1.jpg idoesn't get displayed.  So all this time it was image2 rendering twice. Third upload makes three times the images. and so on....

Comment: Could you please try to reproduce the issue with stackoverflow code snippet or any live editor like fiddle or codesandbox.

Comment: added the snippet

Comment: That's because you set the `change` event listener inside the `click` event listener, so every time you `click` the input, the `change` event listener duplicated and the image duplicated too, So it should be setten outside, I just update the code, please check.